# JSON based data structure for group messaging

Tags: json, database, chat, messaging, inbox

I am trying to add group messaging functionality to the platform I'm working on. The concept of group messaging is more like a client ~ customerservice communication tool. As our backend stores data in JSON format only (no relational database whatsoever) I want to have an idea of what would be the most efficient way to store the messaging data.

Here are some details about it:

- Messaging is not necessarily real time
- Each message thread starts by a single client it will be visible to all customer service agents on the dashboard.
- We have to store information about when each customerservice agent has read the messaging thread.
- Either of customer service agents are able to answer to client at any point during the conversation that makes the conversation like a group messaging with client on one side and several agents on the other side.

Any thoughts on the best practice to form data structure for this application in JSON?

Comment: Any suggestions will totally depend on your use cases around how you need to read this data.  For example, are you always going to read the whole thread structure every time, or are you going to need to access the data in different ways - by client, by agent, etc.?  As written, this question is much too broad in scope.

Comment: access would be by both client and agent (both will see the thread) but we might want to show some extra information to agents (like which other agents have read the thread or etc). 

We are not expecting extra-long threads for this feature so it would be possible to load entire thread in most cases but it would be good to consider a dividing method just for rare cases of extra long threads.